# How do I make entry boxes in a second window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to make an entry box for people to enter their names, as part of a "registration" for a mini-program that I am doing, but the result is that an entry box doesn't appear at all.

Here is the section of the code that is troubling me:

```
def win2(self):
    # this is the child window
    board = Toplevel()
    board.title("Sign up")
    board.focus_set()
    board.grab_set()

    userVar = StringVar()
    userVar.set('Username')

    square1Label = Label(board,textvariable=userVar)
    square1Label.grid(row=0, column=7)

    userEnt=Entry(self)
    userEnt.grid(row=1, column=7)

    s2Var = StringVar()
    s2Var.set('First Name')
    square2Label = Label(board,textvariable=s2Var)
    square2Label.grid(row=1, column=7)

    leaveButton = Button(board, text="Quit", command=board.destroy)
    leaveButton.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nw')
    board.wait_window(board)
```

And here is the coding in full, minus the importing of Tkinter and the mainloop:

```
class Application(Frame):
    """GUI Application for making Baakibook"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Initialize the frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="light blue")
        self.win1()

    # different windows
    def win1(self):
        # this is the main/root window
        signupButton = Button(root, text="Sign up", command=self.win2)
        signupButton.grid(row=9, column=7)
        loginButton = Button(root, text="Log in", command=self.win3)
        loginButton.grid(row=10, column=7)
        leaveButton = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
        leaveButton.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nw')
        b1Var = StringVar()
        b2Var = StringVar()

        b1Var.set('b1')
        b2Var.set('b2')
        box1Label = Label(root,textvariable=b1Var,width=12)
        box1Label.grid(row=3, column=2)
        box2Label = Label(root,textvariable=b2Var,width=12)
        box2Label.grid(row=3, column=3)
        root.mainloop()


    def win2(self):
        # this is the child window
        board = Toplevel()
        board.title("Sign up")
        board.focus_set()
        board.grab_set()

        userVar = StringVar()
        userVar.set('Username')

        square1Label = Label(board,textvariable=userVar)
        square1Label.grid(row=0, column=7)

        userEnt=Entry(self)
        userEnt.grid(row=1, column=7)

        s2Var = StringVar()
        s2Var.set('First Name')
        square2Label = Label(board,textvariable=s2Var)
        square2Label.grid(row=1, column=7)

        leaveButton = Button(board, text="Quit", command=board.destroy)
        leaveButton.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nw')
        board.wait_window(board)

    def win3(self):
        # this is the child window
        board = Toplevel()
        board.title("Login User")
        board.focus_set()
        board.grab_set()

        s1Var = StringVar()
        s2Var = StringVar()
        s1Var.set("s1")
        s2Var.set("s2")

        square1Label = Label(board,textvariable=s1Var)
        square1Label.grid(row=0, column=7)
        square2Label = Label(board,textvariable=s2Var)
        square2Label.grid(row=0, column=6)

        leaveButton = Button(board, text="Quit", command=board.destroy)
        leaveButton.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nw')
        board.wait_window(board)
```

Comment: Do you need to call `columnconfigure` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument you use to create the widget is what parent you want it assigned to. So, this line:

```
userEnt=Entry(self)
userEnt.grid(row=1, column=7)
```

makes the `Entry` widget in the `Frame` that you created in `__init__`. If you want it to appear in the `Toplevel`, create it like the other widgets you made in that method, ie:

```
userEnt=Entry(board)
userEnt.grid(row=1, column=7)
```

Also, your grid in the `Toplevel` doesn't make sense right now and a couple of your widgets will appear stacked until you change it.